# Assigning different values in Python Pandas based on criteria

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, missing-data, data-manipulation

I am trying to clean up the data. For the first name variable, I would like to 1) assign missing value (NaN) to those entries that have one character only, 2) assign missing value if it contains only two characters AND one of the characters is a symbol (ie: ".", or "?"), and 3) convert "wm" to string "william"

I tried the following and other codes, but none seems to work:

import pandas as pd
    from pandas import DataFrame, Series
    import numpy as np
    import re

```
def CleanUp():

    data = pd.read_csv("C:\sample.csv")
    frame2 = DataFrame(data)
    frame2.columns = ["First Name", "Ethnicity"]

    # Convert weird values to missing value
    for Name in frame2["First_Name"]:
        if len(Name) == 1:
            Name == np.nan
        if (len(Name) == 2) and (Name.str.contain(".|?|:", na=False)):
            Name == np.nan
        if Name == "wm":
            Name == "william"

    print frame2["First_Name"]
```

Comment: The magic of pandas is to not iterate unless you absolutely have to. You don't have to. look into pandas.DataFrame.replace: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: I try the following: frame2["First_Name"].replace(to_replace="wm", value="william"). Doesn't work.

Comment: works in my example below. let me know what doesnt work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `df.replace`

make up some data:

```
np.random.seed(3)
n=6
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : np.random.choice(['wm','bob','harry','chickens'], size=n), 
                   'timeStamp' : np.random.randint(1000, size=n)})
print df

       Name  timeStamp
0     harry        256
1        wm        789
2       bob        659
3  chickens        714
4        wm        875
5        wm        681
```

run the replace:

```
df.Name = df.Name.replace('wm','william')
print df

       Name  timeStamp
0     harry        256
1   william        789
2       bob        659
3  chickens        714
4   william        875
5   william        681
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I forgot to set the value to equate the new value as in 'frame2["First_Name"] = frame2["First_Name"].replace(to_replace="wm", value="william"). Thank you.

Comment: That won't be the last time you make that mistake. I do it all the time ;)